# Error using JSTL XML taglib - attribute xml does not accept any expressions

Tags: xml, jstl, xslt, el, taglib

I'm getting the following error when I try to use the JSTL XML taglib:

```
/server-side-transform.jsp(51,0) 
According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file,
attribute xml does not accept any expressions
```

I'm looking into the tlds etc, but if anyone knows what this is an can save me some time, it'd be appreciated!

If it helps, I get this error running the example code

```
<c:set var="xml">
  <paragraph>
    This document uses <bold>unusual</bold> markup,
    which we want to replace with <bold>HTML</bold>.
  </paragraph>
</c:set>

<c:set var="xsl">
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="paragraph">
      <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bold">
      <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>

</c:set>

<x:transform xml="${xml}" xslt="${xsl}"/>
```

in my /server-side-transform.jsp - my taglib directives are:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>
```

and I do have standard.jar and jstl.jar in /WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is picking up an "incorrect" version of x-1_0.tld, probably due to classpath issues. I see for instance on my current classpath, I have one version of x-1_0.tld that ALLOWS runtime-expressions ${syntax} in this tag and one that does not. The one in standard.jar does not allow EL expressions, while the one I have in jetty does.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the Sun documentation refers to the URI as

http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml

The tag is now being called correctly, so this was the cause of the problem; however I am getting a NullPointerException in doEndTag()... ho hum

Comment: JSTL1.1 is <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x"%>, the other is 1.0

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, you should use

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>`

to use JSTL 1.1.

Unfortunately the standard.jar files includes many versions of *.tld tag for eg.

- c-1_0-rt.tld
- c-1_0.tld
- c.tld
- fmt-1_0-rt.tld
- fmt-1_0.tld
- fmt.tld
- fn.tld
- permittedTaglibs.tld
- scriptfree.tld
- sql-1_0-rt.tld
- sql-1_0.tld
- sql.tld
- x-1_0-rt.tld
- x-1_0.tld
- x.tld

so by using

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>`

you tell the jsp to specifically use JSTL 1.1 which btw fixes the above issue, if this does not work try using

`<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>`

which basically tells jsp to evaluate EL.

/srm

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
```

Instead of:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was asked quite a while ago but I just ran into the same problem. In my case, the example I was following directed me to use:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

When I should have been using:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

I was staring at the solution for a while before the extra **jsp** in the uri popped out at me.

Comment: I'd rather have your answer integrated in  [@Brabster's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/377559/413020): yours, being much more up-to-date, _only_ contributes with nicer formatting (I had to read it a few times to be sure you don't say anything new).

Answer (score 0):

change <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %> is not right for me.
for my project(web-app version="3.0" )  IDE(MyEclipse)
I see the configuration file of x.tld.There is the false of select which do not allow the select apperance ${} or <%=%>.So I got a way to cheat in the web.xml.

1. `<jsp-config>
       <taglib>
           <taglib-uri>/huang</taglib-uri>
           <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/x.tld</taglib-location>
       </taglib>
   </jsp-config>`  add to web.xml
2. declare the new taglib-url name "huang" to my jsp file like this:

   `<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="/huang" %>`
3. to use`<x:out select="$casexml//案例//${node.name }" />`

   I can get the right result